# Recursively read directory and create object in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I've been struggling with trying to automate and clean up how I utilize sprite generation and loading in my HTML5 game using a NodeJS socket.io server to send an object containing the data needed to generate the sprites.

What I want to do to achieve this is to read through a directory `/img` and all its subdirectories (`/assets1`, `/assets2`, `/assets3`, etc) and create an object based on the data and structure of them. The problem I came across was that I couldn't find a nice way to handle the sub directories of, say, `/assets3`. Here's how my assets are setup as an example:

[image: Directory structure]

And here's the object example that I want to achieve but haven't without just using endless `if`/`else`s which honestly doesn't seem appealing to me and there has got to be a better way with the usage of a library.

```
var outputWeWant = {
  assets1: {
    img1: '/img/assets1/img1.png',
    img2: '/img/assets1/img2.png',
  },
  assets2: {
    img1: '/img/assets2/img1.png',
    img2: '/img/assets2/img2.png',
  },
  assets3: {
    img1: '/img/assets3/img1.png',
    img2: '/img/assets3/img2.png',
    assets4: {
      img1: '/img/assets3/assets4/img1.png'
    }
  }
}
```

Below is just a little bit of brainstorming I did, but this isn't as effective as I want down the road and it looks disgusting having all the is a directory check as we add a new directory into assets4

```
  fs.readdirSync('/img/').map(dirName => {
    fs.readdirSync('/img/' + dirName).map(fileName => {
      if (fs.statSync('/img/' + dirName + '/' + fileName).isDirectory()) {
        // Read the new directory and add the files to our object
      } else {
        // It's not a directory, just add it to our object
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Can you add the code you’ve already tried using to generate the object?

Comment: I assume you're referring to the if/else code? If not, I've not come up with a way to do it any other way and that's why I'm asking perhaps for a bit of direction in the form of a library or helpful advice. :)

Comment: It would be good to see what you’ve got so far, even just as a reference for how you’re interacting with the filesystem

Comment: Thi can help you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra

Comment: @MarceloFilho Why add a [30kB *minified*](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=fs-extra@7.0.1) dependency for what amounts to less than a dozen lines of code?

Comment: @MTCoster why not? Why reinvent the wheel every time?

Comment: What is 30kb to a backend? haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of potentially infinite operation calls for a [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). I’m going to assume this function is to be written for Node, and I’ll leave the filesystem details to the OP. **This snippet should be treated as pseudo-code.**

```
function parseDirectory(directory) {
  return directory.getItems().reduce((out, item) => {
    switch (item.type) {
      case 'file':
        out[item.name] = item.path;
        break;

      case 'directory':
        out[item.name] = parseDirectory(item.path);
        break;
    }

    return out;
  }, {});
}
```

---

With the added `fs` code in the OP, here’s a (theoretically) working function:

```
function parseDirectory(directory) {
  return fs.readdirSync(directory).reduce((out, item) => {
    const itemPath = `${directory}/${item}`;

    if (fs.statSync(itemPath).isDirectory()) {
      out[item] = parseDirectory(itemPath);
    } else {
      out[item] = itemPath;
    }

    return out;
  }, {});
}
```

Of if the syntax of [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is too contrived for your liking, try this:

```
function parseDirectory(directory) {
  let out = {};

  fs.readdirSync(directory).forEach(item => {
    const itemPath = `${directory}/${item}`;

    if (fs.statSync(itemPath).isDirectory()) {
      out[item] = parseDirectory(itemPath);
    } else {
      out[item] = itemPath;
    }
  });

  return out;
}
```

Comment: The first one gave me an idea on how to do it, thanks!